# How does priorityClass Works

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-pod, pod-priority

I try to use priorityClass.

I create two pods, the first has system-node-critical priority and the second cluster-node-critical priority.

Both pods need to run in a node labeled with nodeName: k8s-minion1 but such a node has only 2 cpus while both pods request 1.5 cpu.
I then expect that the second pod runs and the first is in pending status. Instead, the first pod always runs no matter the classpriority I affect to the second pod.

I even tried to label the node afted I apply my manifest but does not change anything.

Here is my manifest :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: firstpod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: container
    image: nginx
    resources:
      requests:
        cpu: 1.5
  nodeSelector:
    nodeName: k8s-minion1
  priorityClassName: cluster-node-critical
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: secondpod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: container
    image: nginx
    resources:
      requests:
        cpu: 1.5
  priorityClassName: system-node-critical
  nodeSelector:
    nodeName: k8s-minion1
```

It is worth noting that I get an error `"unknown object : priorityclass"` when I do `kubectl get priorityclass` and when I export my running pod in yml with `kubectl get pod secondpod -o yaml`, I cant find any `classpriority:` field.

Here Are my version infos:

```
$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"10", GitVersion:"v1.10.0", GitCommit:"fc32d2f3698e36b93322a3465f63a14e9f0eaead", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-03-26T16:55:54Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"} 
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"10", GitVersion:"v1.10.0+coreos.0", GitCommit:"6bb2e725fc2876cd94b3900fc57a1c98ca87a08b", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-04-02T16:49:31Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Any ideas why this is not working?

Thanks in advance,

Abdelghani

Comment: What is your kube version? You may running an older version which doesn't support it.

Comment: Thx @Faheem for your answer. I just added my version info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PriorityClasses first appeared in [k8s 1.8 as alpha feature](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG/CHANGELOG-1.8.md#scheduling-1).
It [graduated to beta in 1.11](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG/CHANGELOG-1.11.md#graduated-to-beta)

You are using 1.10 and this means that this feature is in alpha.

Alpha features are not enabled by default so you would need to enable it.

Unfortunately k8s version 1.10 is no longer supported, so I'd suggest to upgrade at least to 1.14 where [priorityClass feature](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/pod-priority-preemption/) became stable.

Comment: Tkx for your answer but shouldnt I have a notification from kubernetes when this happens?

Comment: [Here is the piece of code](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.10/pkg/apis/core/validation/validation.go#L2978-L2984) responsible for validation of this specific field. As you can see, its skipping validation if feature is disabled, but this field exists and k8s is aware of it. It's just ignoring it @Abdelghani

Comment: Thks @HelloWorld. I am not familiar with K8s Go code but if I understand it well, the parser checks the priorityclass feature only if it is supported. Otherwise, it does nothing (no warning message). Do you know if this behavior is intended and is there a paricular reason for that?

Comment: Is I already mentioned, in version 1.10 this feature in in alpha stage so don't be supprised if its not working as you expect. @Abdelghani